# Вывод связанной категории из БД с картинками

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Столкнулсья с проблемой извлечь инфы из БД.Проблема такая что нужно из БД выводить информацию из категории.

Есть 2 таблиц `category` и `press` в БД

В category есть 2 поле с которыми я работаю `image` и `name` соответственно имя и картинка категории.

И в press есть 2 поле `text`(информация ) и `category` во втором хранитсья какой категории относитсья этот текст соответственно .

Нужно выводить  так :

> картинка соответсвующей категории потом его текст в списке **ul li**. потом
>   картинка следующей категории и потом его текст и так д.

Мои попытки..

Первая попытка

```
<?php 

global $db; //берем подключения из БД
$rows = $db->query("SELECT `image` FROM `category`"); //берем все картинки из БД

    foreach($rows as $row){ //в цикле проходимсья по ним
        $img = $row["image"]; 

?>

<div class="blue">
    <img class="title-img" src="../upload/<?php echo $img; ?>"> //присваиваем картинку в цикле из папки
    <?php } ?> закрываем область работы foreach цикла

    <?php 
            global $db;
            $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `press`"); //берем все данные из таблицы press

            foreach($rows as $row){ //проходимсья
                $text = $row["text"]; //берем текст от туда

        ?>
    <ul>

        <li><?php  echo $text; ?></li> //и выводим текст

    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Такая конструкция выводила всех тегов одного внутри другова то есть были вложенные теги с классом `blue`(один класс blue внутри с элементами потом  другой класс blue  с его элементами) до того как не закончились элементы внутри БД

Вторая попытка

```
<?php 

global $db;
$rows = $db->query("SELECT `image` FROM `category`");

    foreach($rows as $row){
        $img = $row["image"];

?>

<!-- <div class="blue> -->
    <img class="title-img" src="../upload/<?php echo $img; ?>">
    <?php } ?>


    <ul>
        <?php
            global $db;
            $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `press`");

            foreach($rows as $row){
                $text = $row["text"];

        ?>
        <li><?php  echo $text; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

Вторая попытка аналогично первому ничего не получилось но в этот раз у меня получилось хотя бы не показывать элементов одного внутри другово.

Текст вывелось в одном `ul` внутри всех `li` а картинки категорий наверху один за другим без вложенности.

Попыток было больше чем 2 если бы я написал всех боюсь места бы не хватило тут помогите пожалуйста очень прошу.Насчет безопасности знаю мой код уязвим для иньекции.

Comment: В `category` добавьте поле `press_id`, а в `press` поле `id`, тогда с помощью `join` вы объедините это дело одним запросом и не будет мороки.

Comment: @Manitikyl у всех таблиц есть строка `id` в автоинкременте .У меня почти получилось я взял все данные а не только картинку из таблицы `category` а потом сравнивал их если переменная из таблицы press в строке category(а там хранятсья имя категорий) совпадает с переменным `name`(это имя категории тут также хранится изображения категории) из таблицы `category` то делаем так  внутри if __echo "<li>" .   $text . "</li>"__ осталось только мне понять как правильно выбирать изображения под нужный текст из категории.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почти доделал.

1.Вместо того чтобы взять только картинку я взял все данные из таблицы `category`

2.Переменная `name` нужно чтобы сравнивать его с другим переменным (`$category_name`) из другой таблицы (`press`)

3.Если они совпали создавать тег `li` в котором лежит переменная `$text` которая берет текст из БД

```
<?php 

global $db;
$rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `category`"); //1.

    foreach($rows as $row){
        $img = $row["image"];
        $name = $row["name"]; 
?>

<!-- <div class="baku-ws"> -->
    <img class="title-img" src="../upload/<?php echo $img; ?>">

    <ul>
        <?php
            global $db;
            $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `press`");

            foreach($rows as $row){
                $text = $row["text"];
                $category_name = $row["category"];
                if($category_name == $name){ //2
                    echo "<li>" .   $text . "</li>"; //3
                }

        ?>

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Осталось только сделать чтобы каждая картинка выходила над соответсвующим текстом.

Comment: Это просто - `if($category_name == $name){ вывести картинку }`. У вас очень плохо организован код и логика. Я советую все таки уделить время архитектуре приложений.

Comment: @Manitikyl Что посоветуете насчет архитектуры?Я не знаю как мне быть по этому.И насчет картинки не сработало =(  __echo "<img class='title-img' src'../upload/" . $this->$img . ">";__

Comment: `$this->$img` - откуда хоть. Просто `$img`. А по поводу архитектуры: ну блин, можете сами свою разработать (сперва погуглив что и как) либо возьмите фреймворк, если не хотите сильно заморачиваться, то посмотрите CodeIgniter. Старичок, и прост в освоении.

Comment: @Manitikyl спасибо огромное . а насчет фреймворка я сторонник Ларавель.

Comment: ну либо лару используйте. он просто посложнее будет, я думал вы вообще не работали с фреймами. в любом случае то что вы пишите не по ларавельскому

Comment: @Manitikyl вы правы я не работал с фреймворками проста учусь и начал с чистого php потом хочу перейти на лару .

Comment: Разницы не будет, поверьте :)